NetSuite Sandbox Setup: Deployment and Certificate Status Stuck 'In Progress' for 3 Days - Is This Normal?
I am trying to finish setting up a sandbox website in netsuite. DNS Status and DNS verification Status is configured correctly. Deployment and certificate status is in progress and has been for three days now. I am brand new to Netsuite, does it usually take this long for the deployment and certificate status? Anyone ever have this issue?
I have reached out to support and am waiting for a response.
